# Remove instance of square brackets, if found two successive instances

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a data in following manner:

```
{"id": "sugarcrm", "text": "sugarcrm", "children": [ [ { "id": "accounts", "text": "accounts", "children": [ { "id": "id", "text": "id" }, { "id": "name", "text": "name" } ] } ] ] }
```

Now, I want to remove the instance of square bracket i.e. `[` and `]` if there are two successive instances like this `[ [` or `] ]`.

Now if you see the above data, you'll get to see that there are instances of `[` and `]` which are repeated twice successively. So I want to remove one instance of each.

Now, I can check the two successively repeated instances of each and remove one, like this

```
$text = '{"id": "sugarcrm", "text": "sugarcrm", "children": [ [ { "id": "accounts", "text": "accounts", "children": [ { "id": "id", "text": "id" }, { "id": "name", "text": "name" } ] } ] ] }';

echo preg_replace('/\[ \[+/', '[', $text);
```

Now, the above code is for `[`. So to remove the successively repeated instance of `]`, I'll have to repeat the same code again.

I want to know, is there a better way to achieve the same result or not. Meanwhile, I can work it out, but still what if, in future, I'll have to do the same for any other character? Kindly guide me here.

Comment: Since it seems like a JSON, there is no way of nesting curly braces, as it represents an object and requires a key of type string.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I'll refactor my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are processing a json string.  It is contraindicated to attempt string manipulations (with regex or other) because there are very possible pitfalls with "over-matching".

While I don't fully understand the variability of your data structure, I can provide some temporary guidance by converting your json string to an array and then safely modifying the data with an array function.

Consider this:

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1032943457b252ed434c028d47da4e2eea018153))

```
$json='{"id": "sugarcrm", "text": "sugarcrm", "children": [ [ { "id": "accounts", "text": "accounts", "children": [ { "id": "id", "text": "id" }, { "id": "name", "text": "name" } ] } ] ] }';
$array=json_decode($json,true);  // convert to array
foreach($array as &$a){  // $a is modifiable by reference
    if(is_array($a) && isset($a[0]) && isset($a[0][0])){  // check if array and if two consecutive/nested indexed subarrays
        $a=array_column($a,0); // effectively shift deeper subarray up one level
    }
}
$json=json_encode($array);
echo $json;
```

Output:

```
{"id":"sugarcrm","text":"sugarcrm","children":[{"id":"accounts","text":"accounts","children":[{"id":"id","text":"id"},{"id":"name","text":"name"}]}]}
```

---

For that matter, if you *know* where the double-nested-indexes are, then you can access them without looping (or modifying by reference) like this:

```
$json='{"id": "sugarcrm", "text": "sugarcrm", "children": [ [ { "id": "accounts", "text": "accounts", "children": [ { "id": "id", "text": "id" }, { "id": "name", "text": "name" } ] } ] ] }';
$array=json_decode($json,true);
$array['children']=array_column($array['children'],0);  // modify 2 known, nested, indexed subarrays
$json=json_encode($array);
echo $json;
```

Answer (score -1):

How about:

```
echo str_replace(array('[ [', '] ]'), array('[', ']'), $text);
```

Comment: yeah, it is working, but what if the whitespace between the two instance of brackets are missing? Then your code won't work. And what if, in future, I'll have to do the same for any other character?